# How to have an apache module and dependent shared library in Autoconf/Automake project

Tags: c, apache, autoconf, automake, apache-modules

I'm developing a apache module and a shared library in the same Autoconf/Automake project. How my Makefile.am should be?

Now it is:

```
INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)

nobase_include_HEADERS =  \
  foo.h \
  bar.h 

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
  foo.c \
  bar.c 

libfoo_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 0:0:0
```

I can add these lines:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = mod_foo.la
mod_foo_la_SOURCES = mod_foo.c
mod_foo_la_LDFLAGS = -module
mod_foo_la_LIBADD = libfoo.la
```

Is it right?

how to make install the module with APXS and the shared library with libtool?
If i put:

```
install:
    $(APXS) -i -a -n foo mod_foo.la
```

I think the libfoo.la it is not installed but only the module.

Comment: I'm not familiar with APXS, so I can't help.  However the `INCLUDES` variable is deprecated and should be replaced by `AM_CPPFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's being installed because you're overriding the `install` target. Try using `install-exec-local` ([manual](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Extending)):

```
install-exec-local:
    $(APXS) -i -a -n foo mod_foo.la
```

(Note that I don't know `APXS`, I'm just copying your rule.)

You should also define an `uninstall-local` target to clean up.